# Chicken and egg problem: show that every singleton in a hereditarily compact Hausdorff space is clopen

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing, compactness

> Proposition: Show that every singleton in a hereditarily compact
>   Hausdorff space is clopen

Recall, a space is hereditarily compact if every subset is compact.

**My attempt:**

> Let $x \in X$, then $\{x\}$ as a singleton is compact since every
>   single subset is compact. It is compact in a Hausdorff space, so it is
>   closed. Then given $x\neq y \in X$,  $X \backslash \bigcup_{x \in
>  X\backslash \{y\}} \{x\} = \{y\}$
>
> The next step is that I wish to show $\{y\}$ is open. But this is only
>   true if $X$ is finite $\implies \bigcup_{x \in
>  X\backslash \{y\}} \{x\}$ is closed (finite union of closed is closed).
>
> But to prove that $X$ is finite, I must show that all singletons are
>   open. By contrapositive, $\{\{x\}|x\in X\}$ forms an open cover
>   without finite subcover hence $X$ is not compact iff it is not finite.
>
> How to resolve this chicken-egg problem?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that Hausdorff spaces are $T_1$, but also that compact subsets of Hausdorff spaces are closed.

Comment: Oh...so just consider $X\backslash (X \backslash \{y\}) = \{y\}$

Comment: Yes. You already had the ingredients for a quickie proof. You just missed your exit, and had to take a longer route.